# MOMENTJS TIME FORMATTING

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have this data :

```
time: "2020-12-17T13:06:13.144Z"
```

and then I want change this data, to be like this...

```
"17-12-2020 13:06:13"
```

but when I change with this code:

```
{moment(time).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss")}
```

**MY OUTPUT IS NOW :**

```
"17-12-2020 20:06:13"
```

**MY OUTPUT EXPECTATION:**

```
"17-12-2020 13:06:13"
```

How can I change this format so that it matches my expectation?

Answer (score 1):

Try `utc()` method before `format`:

```
moment(time).utc().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: it same...Output : "17-12-2020 20:06:13"...not my output expectation

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom string in moment format string with `[:]`

Try this
 `{moment(time).format("["]DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss["]")}`